# How to load and call java compiled classes from within C?

Tags: java, c, class, jvm

How to load and call java compiled classes from within C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Calling a Java Method from Native Code](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CJniJava.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JNI.  There are many good links and tutorials (including the two cited above).

Comment: It is much easier to call C from Java than the other way around.